# How do I keep the apostrophes when importing csv to sqlite

Tags: sql, csv, import

I am using an SQL database in an android app and have encountered a problem with apostrophes.

My database is a quotes database which I have in MS Excel 2007, then saved in .csv format. I then imported this into the sql table I have for the app. However the quotes with an apostrophe are not displaying correctly in the database (and therefore the app). Each apostrophe is replaced with a character that is invisible. I know it is there because of the character count and the fact that in the word "aren't" for example which looks like "arent" it take 3 clicks of the right arrow to get from the left side of the n to the right side of the t. If I manually add an apostrophe to the sql table it converts back to this invisible character when the database is saved. In the android app this invisible character shows up as a hollow rectangle.

I am sure the issue does not lie in my app's displaying of the quote because I have passed in a String to the same code and it displays apostrophes perfectly fine.

Is there a way to fix this issue, possibly by changing the character set or something like that? or does SQL not support apostrophes?

Answer (score 0):

Since a single quote and apostrophe are the same character you have to do something in sql to tell the database when to treat it as part of a string or when to use it to surround a string.  In every RDBMS of which I am aware, if you want the character to be part of a string, you "quote the quote", ie you change ' to '' when talking to your database.

That seems to be only part of your problem.  The other part is that your android app displays this character as a rectangle instead or an apostrophe.  That's got nothing to do with sql.  That is a function of the android application.

Comment: Thanks I think this should work. I just included the other information about the app for completeness - hence I didn't tag the question with 'android'.One question though - do I change the ' to '' in the .csv file? I just did this and have a very similar problem but there are now 2 invisible characters instead of one.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem - any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution to the problem.

At runtime of the app I'm replacing the invisible character with an apostrophe and the final string is then how the quote should look.

```
String quote = (get the quote from the SQL table)
char[] tempQuoteCharArr = new char[quote.length()];
tempQuoteCharArr = quote.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < quote.length(); i++){
        if(tempQuoteCharArr[i] == ''){
            tempQuoteCharArr[i] = '\'';
        }
    }
    quote = String.valueOf(tempQuoteCharArr);
```

The invisible character is between the single quotes in the if statement.